# SQL Select Sum Query

Tags: sql, types, group-by, sum, case

I need to complete the following but need to SUM on EntryValue where EntryType= 'C' - EntryType = 'D' but not sure where to include it.

```
SELECT SUM(EntryValue) AS EntryValue, Left(Warehouse,1) AS Branch 
FROM GenJournalDetail INNER JOIN InvJournalCtl ON (GenJournalDetail.GlPeriod = InvJournalCtl.LedgPeriod) AND (GenJournalDetail.GlYear = InvJournalCtl.YearPostLedg) AND (GenJournalDetail.Journal = InvJournalCtl.GlJournal)
WHERE GenJournalDetail.GlCode = 'Z5207550' AND GlYear = '2011' AND GlPeriod = '10' 
GROUP BY Left(InvJournalCtl.Warehouse,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Select it then group it;

```
SELECT SUM(EntryValue) AS EntryValueTotal, EntryType, Left(Warehouse,1) AS Branch 
...
GROUP BY Left(InvJournalCtl.Warehouse,1), EntryType
```

**Edit** I didn't realise you wanted to deduct;

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE EntryType
        WHEN 'C' THEN EntryValue
        ELSE 0 END
    )
    -
    SUM(CASE EntryType
        WHEN 'D' THEN EntryValue
        ELSE 0 END
    ) AS EntryValueTotal, 
    Left(Warehouse,1) AS Branch 
FROM GenJournalDetail 
  INNER JOIN InvJournalCtl ON (GenJournalDetail.GlPeriod = InvJournalCtl.LedgPeriod) AND (GenJournalDetail.GlYear = InvJournalCtl.YearPostLedg) AND (GenJournalDetail.Journal = InvJournalCtl.GlJournal)
WHERE 
  GenJournalDetail.GlCode = 'Z5207550' AND GlYear = '2011' AND GlPeriod = '10' 
GROUP BY Left(InvJournalCtl.Warehouse,1)
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry I have EntryValue on the brain, the field I need to refine by is if EntryType = 'D' not Entry Value

Comment: @t-clausen.dk yeah your right, I didn't pay enough attention to the question, SUM(EntryValue) where EntryValue could be a character makes no sense

Comment: Do i need to group by the EntryType? I need to minus one from the other to give a total.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you wanted to deduct

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sum the column add it in the select and group:

```
SELECT SUM(EntryValue) AS TotEntry, ...
...
GROUP BY ...
```

you don't need to group an aggregated column; you need to filter query too?

Comment: Do i need to group by the EntryType? I need to minus one from the other to give a total.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you need. What you wanna get with the query?

Comment: You're right! I change the code with the old one you'll never get the sum but a repeat of EntryValue...
But I continue to don't understand his needs.